# Using Selenium in Python to access hidden table in JavaScript website

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to use Selenium webdriver with Python to open an HTML link that seems to be hidden within a JavaScript table, which is in an iframe. I know the last 2 lines are not currently doing very much.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

# Open MasterControl

url = *****

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = r'C:\Users\jmiller\Desktop\MasterControl Scraping\chromedriver')
driver.get(url)

# Login using my credentials

username = driver.find_element_by_id('userid')
password = driver.find_element_by_name('password')

username.send_keys('*****')
password.send_keys('*****')

submitButton = driver.find_element_by_id('MCP_BUTTON_40') 
submitButton.click()

# Search for assets

asset = driver.find_element_by_id('strSearchPortal')
asset.send_keys('****')

goButton = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@type = 'submit']")
goButton.click()

# Open asset form

driver.switch_to.frame('myframe')
element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH,"//div[@id = 'folder_Forms']/div[@id = 'row2']/div[@id = 'column_i.title_nm']/a")))
element.click()
```

'folder_Forms' seems to be where I'm getting lost. The link I want to click his hidden until you click on the "Forms" icon on the website. Do I have to execute the JavaScript "toggleFolder" function? Any help is greatly appreciated. Let me know if more info would be helpful - I'm trying to avoid copying over the entire site.

```
<div id="folder_Forms" class="listDataTable" style="margin-left: 10px;width: 99%;"> 
            <span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="toggleFolder('image_Forms','group_Forms');">
                <img src="*****" id="image_Forms" title="Hide Content">

                    Forms

            </span>

            <span style="font-weight:lighter;font-size:11px;color:#666666; " onclick="toggleFolder('image_Forms','group_Forms');">(3 records)
            </span>

            <span>



            </span>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to execute `toogleFolder` with `execute_script`, and you will see if it helps

```
driver.execute_script("toggleFolder('image_Forms','group_Forms');")
```